# LeanFT - Unable to enable the LeanFT Object Identification center

Tags: leanft

I installed LeanFT as an Eclipse plugin but I'm unable to enable the LeanFT OIC center (Object Identification Center).

Comment: Well.... is the engine running? Is there an error shown? Is the computer turned on?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to try is disable the LeanFT plugin from Eclipse and then enable again this should resolve your problem.
If it still persists then check the compatibility of LeanFT with eclipse you are using.